# Subreport as a header in main report (with page numbering)

Tags: reporting-services

I'm facing an odd issue: I'm going to create lots of reports using reporting services (SSRS) and one request was to create a subreport that will be shown as a header in main report. I've come across two main problems:

1. It is not possible to insert subreports into report headers. I thought of a possible workaround and just create a subreport without header and then insert subreport on top of body in main report. But then I faced another problem:
2. My header contains a logo, title and page number. However, function for page numbering cannot be used in report body, only in header.

Is there any alternative? Or should i just add a header to each report instead of trying to create a subreport for the header?

Answer (score 3):

You can start by using a report with the header as a template. You would start with this whenever you make a new report. That at least eliminates the need to recreate it each time.

If you do want to be able to manage the headers dynamically, you can use a data-driven approach. Almost all of the properties for images and text boxes can be defined with expressions. And the expressions can refer to a dataset. In other words, you can store all of your preferences in a table. Your header template would include a dataset that brings in all the settings. Then you can use expressions to define how the header will look.

By doing this, you would be able to adjust the image, font size, etc. in all the headers at once just by changing a value in your table. Obviously there is some overhead with setting up the template this way, but it has a negligible performance impact and gives you more power to manage the header dynamically.

Comment: Thank you! I have just one question - how would I handle images? Do I store an image path in the table?

Comment: Yeah, I usually store paths, but you can also Base64 encode the images directly in the table. I find it easier to manage images when they are on the report server. Keep in mind that the images on the server won't show up in preview, but will work once you deploy.